# Bootstrapping moderately extreme quantile regression

Tags: bootstrap, quantiles, extreme-value, quantile-regression

Let $(Y_1, X_1), \dots, (Y_n, X_n)$ be iid sequence drawn from $F$. For a fixed $q\in (0,1)$, consider the linear q-quantile regression $Q_Y(q|x) = \beta_qx$, where $Q_Y(\cdot\mid x)$ is the conditional quantile of $Y$ given $X=x$. Estimating $\beta_q$ is easy for fixed $q$ using $$\hat{\beta_q} \in \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{t=1}^{n} \rho_{q}(Y_t - X_t\beta),$$ where $\rho(u) := (q-1\{u < 0\})u$. Here, $\hat{\beta_q}$ is consistent and asymptotically normal under some assumptions.

Let $q_n \in (0,1)$ be a sequence of growing quantiles $q_n\to 1,\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-q_n)=\infty$. This is known as intermediately extreme quantile regression:  we are interested in estimating $\beta_{q_n}$ in $Q_Y(q_n|x) = x\beta_{q_n}$. For example, Theorem 5.1 in [1] showed that the classical quantile estimator still works even though $q_n$ grows (under some regularity conditions, it is even asymptotically normal).

**My question: Does a classical bootstrap work for estimating the confidence intervals of** $\beta_q$?  By classical bootstrap, I mean randomly sampling, with replacement, from our dataset to generate multiple bootstrap samples, each matching the size of our original dataset and computing $\hat{\beta}_{q_n}$ in each. Then, the upper confidence interval will be the $95\%$ quantile from the bootstrapped values.  But if you have a better modification of bootstrap in mind, let me know.

Note: [2] is an interesting related article that shows when extreme bootstrapping works in peak-over-threshold problems, but it does not relate to regression-type problems.

[1] V. Chernozhukov. Extremal quantile regression. The Annals of Statistics, 33(2):806–839, 2005

[2] Laurens de Haan & Chen Zhou (2022) Bootstrapping Extreme Value Estimators, Journal of the American Statistical Association, DOI: 10.1080/01621459.2022.2120400

Comment: I would expect that the conditions making $\hat\beta$ asymptotically Normal would suffice to make it bootstrappable,  because  that seems fairly generally true in iid data (by either the delta-method argument in van der Vaart or by Donsker class argument in vdv & Wellner *Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes* chapter 3.6).  Beyond that I have no clue.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks for the point of view. An interesting question then: Is it true that if our data are iid and the estimator is asymptotically normal, then bootstrap works? I do not see that being a consequence of the delta method. That is only true as long as our estimator is a function of the sample mean, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's true under much weaker conditions: if the estimate is a Hadamard differentiable functional **of the empirical CDF** or a conditional involving Donsker classes. Very commonly, proofs that estimators are asymptotically Normal rely on similar assumptions to these. So although normality isn't a sufficient condition, it's a very strong hint.